# Change the Legend label dynamically in aChartEngine

Tags: android, plot, achartengine

I am displaying sensor data on graph in Android device using aChartEngine library. I have some 6 sensors like A,B,C,D,E,F, and based on user selection graph has to be displayed. Graph is getting displayed properly, but am getting difficulty in changing the Legend label according to the sensor's selected. It keep the same value which we used when creating the XYSeries, after setting that value, is it possible to change it?? I mean

```
XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("A sensor");
```

It will display "A sensor" in graph legend.
Now if user select sensor B, I want to change the Legend value to "B sensor" dynamically, is it possible to change like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per aChartEngine XYSeries [Javadoc](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/model/XYSeries.html) the constructor you are using currently

```
XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("A sensor");
```

is setting a title not Legend as per the Javadoc [constructor](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/model/XYSeries.html#XYSeries(java.lang.String)) summary.

So for changing the title dynamically there a method named [setTitle](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/model/XYSeries.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)) available using which you can change from **A sensor** to **B sensor** or whatever based on user selection as

```
incomeSeries.setTitle("B series")
```